# link mysite back to main teamsite- sp2013

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, mysite

I have 2 web app (1 for intranet.domain.com and the other for mysite.domain.com) how to link mysite to intranet site. 1 suggestion seems ok, but I don't know how to implement it is:

```
$webapp.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = '<a href="/" class="ms-core-suiteLink-a">Home</a>'

$webapp.Update():
```

Comment: what you mean by link back to mysite. do you want place a link on every Mysite which points to the team site so that user can click and go to team site?

Comment: yes, i want users to be able to go back to Intranet by clicking a link, when they are in mysite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to run the below powershell on one of the sharePoint server in order to put the Link on your mySite.

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://{your My Site web application}
$webApp.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = "<div class=""ms-core-brandingText""><a href="http:// your team site ">Your Main Portal</a></div>"
$webApp.Update()
```